# Getting Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000] and can't find where it comes from

Tags: php, mysql

I am not new in MySQL, but today my query to insert row into table is not working.

I searched for this exception in Stack Overflow, but none of these help to solve my problem.

The query is:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO groupchanges (change, changetext, groupID, datetime, changer, IPaddr, client) VALUES (:groupID, :change, :changetext, :datetime, :changer, :IPaddr, :client)');

$q2 = $stmt->execute(array(':groupID' => $groupID, ':change' => 'User '. $_SESSION['username'] . ' changed setting ' . $type . ' to ' . $resource, ':changetext' => $_SESSION['username'] . ' muutti ryhmän ' . $groupSetting, ':datetime' => $today, ':changer' => $_SESSION['username'], ':IPaddr' => $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], ':client' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
```

And getting exception:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'change, changetext, groupID, datetime, changer, IPaddr, client) VALUES (?, ?, ?,' at line 1 in /home1/bubos/public_html/homework/web/groupdetails.php:72
Stack trace:
#0 /home1/bubos/public_html/homework/web/groupdetails.php(72): PDO-&gt;prepare('INSERT INTO gro...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home1/bubos/public_html/homework/web/groupdetails.php</b> on line <b>72</b><br />
```

Comment: Isn't it not there in `groupdetails.php (Line 72)`

Comment: @VanTho Thank you for understanding this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`change` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). Use backticks to escape the name

```
INSERT INTO groupchanges (`change`, ...
```

or use a different column name.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for Answer! I did it like you said, but now I got this error: `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'IPaddr' cannot be null`

Comment: Then you have to provide a value for `IPaddr`. Looks like the passed value is `NULL`

Comment: Yes, I realized, that IP address was null. Anyways, It's now working! Now I learned reserved keywords. Thank you eveyone!